# Email notification based on results of an SQL query not working

Tags: php, sql, email

Here's my PHP:

```
#!/cron.php
<?php

$dbconnect = new mysqli('localhost','root','root','serrano');
$query = "SELECT `app`,`email`,`accept` FROM `requests` WHERE `accept`=1";

$result = mysql_query($query);

if($result && $result->num_rows>=1) {
    $subject = "Your application has been accepted for review.";
    $message='Congratulations. Your application "';

    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $message.="{$row['name']}\"";
        $email="{$row['email']}";
    }

    $message.="has been accepted for review at redacted.";
    if(mail($email, $subject, $message)) {
      //mail successfully sent
    } else {
        echo "fail";
    }
  }
?>
```

As far as I'm aware, the query works fine. It returns the relevant rows in the database. What's up with my PHP?

### Code Update 1

Here's the updated PHP, with the mysqli errors corrected. Yet it still returns an error:

*PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function query() on a non-object in [...] on line 5*

```
#!/cron.php
<?php

$dbconnect = new mysqli('localhost','root','root','serrano');
$result->query('SELECT `app`,`email`,`accept` FROM `requests` WHERE `accept`=1');

if($result && $result->num_rows>=1) {
$subject = "Your application has been accepted for review.";
$message='Congratulations. Your application "';

while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $message.="{$row['name']}\"";
    $email="{$row['email']}";
}

$message.="has been accepted for review at redacted.";
if(mail($email, $subject, $message)) {
  //mail successfully sent
} else {
    echo "fail";
}
  }
?>
```

### Working Code

Okay, so here's the working code. Just a few adjustments to the way it is connecting and running the query:

```
#!/cron.php
<?php


$link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','serrano');

$result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT `app`,`email`,`accept` FROM `requests` WHERE  `accept`=1');

if($result->num_rows >= 1){
$subject = "Your application has been accepted for review.";
$message='Congratulations. Your application "';

while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $message.="{$row['app']}\"";
    $email="{$row['email']}";
}

$message.="has been accepted for review at redacted.";
if(mail($email, $subject, $message)) {
  //mail successfully sent
} else {
    echo "fail";
}
 }
?>
```

Comment: Is your e-mail configured correctly? Also, why do you have a `while` loop? That shouldn't even be an `if`.

Comment: Oh, the actual problem is that you're mixing MySQL and MySQLi. Don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `mysqli`, but using `mysql_query` at same time.

It should be `$dbconnect->query()` instead of `mysql_query`.

Comment: Ah thanks for that. But it still returns an error: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function query() on a non-object in [...] on line 5 any ideas?

Comment: @JackGriffiths `$result` doesnt exists, use `$dbconnect` as xdazz said

Comment: @nathanjosiah right... it's still returning an error: Undefined property: mysqli::$num_rows in [..] on line 7 — now I'm completely lost. Line 7 runs thus: if($dbconnect->num_rows >= 1) {

Comment: @JackGriffiths Have you checked the manual? This time should be `$result->num_rows`.

Comment: I'm really not following. We haven't defined $result yet... so how can we have an if statement based on it?

Comment: @Jack What you should do is `$result = $dbconnect->query(...);`